# Improving postgres query performance by descreasing the cost of the query

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am doing the query tuning with one of the existing query in my project eventually the execution time taking is quite longer than usual.
below is my screen shot which indicates the performance of the query.

[image]

can someone could you please help me with the solution to improve the performance of my query.
any small suggestion would be a great help. thanks in advance.

Comment: The cost is just an estimate used for planning purposes.  Your goal should be to make the query actually be faster, not to make the planner think it will be faster.  So look at the measured times, not the estimated costs.  Over 3/4 of the time is going to the first merge join listed under the append.  So opening that puppy up, and see what is inside.  Better yet, give us the entire plan, not some mangled, folded, and truncated guified mess.  And as text, not as an image of text.  You can post it to https://explain.depesz.com/ if it is too big to include here.

Comment: You need the query text, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output and the object definitions to tune queries.